# How to develop configuration interface for custom widget in ArcGIS Flex Application builder?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, flex

I'm trying to know if it's possible to develop a custom configuration interface for custom widgets in ArcGIS Flex Application Builder.

The standard widgets have a nice and shiny configuration interface, with buttons and text-box, but I would like to know if it's possible (and how) to have similar GUI for my custom widgets as well.

I mean, editing XML is note very user friendly and will not fit in what I want to do.

If it's not possible at the moment, is this something planned for this builder?

Answer (score 1):

Customization for flex appliations can be developed using Adobe Flash Builder.  See links below:

[Flex Getting Started for Developers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html#/Getting_started_for_developers/01m30000001q000000/)

[Adobe Flash Builder](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash_builder)